# '+' and '+-' overlay specification behaving inconsistently in presence of subitems

Tags: beamer, overlays, transparency

I have a nested itemize list. I want each item/subitem to uncover one-after-another. I tried using method 1 (using `<+>`), but it didn't work. However method 2 produces expected behaviour. Why this discrepancy? How do I get my intended output?

**Method 1**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+>]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \item a
    \begin{itemize}
        \item b
        \item c
    \end{itemize}
    \item d
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Output*
1. 'a' visible, rest transparent
2. 'c' double-transparent, rest transparent
3. 'b' double-transparent, rest transparent
4. 'd' visible, 'a' transparent, 'b' and 'c' double-transparent

*Intended output*
1. 'a' visible, rest transparent
2. 'b' visible, rest transparent
3. 'c' visible, rest transparent
4. 'd' visible, rest transparent

---

**Method 2**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->] % <-- difference
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \item a
    \begin{itemize}
        \item b
        \item c
    \end{itemize}
    \item d
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

*Output*
1. 'a' visible, rest transparent
2. 'a', 'b' visible, rest transparent
3. 'd' transparent, rest visible
4. All visible

Comment: At first sight, I would say that this is the expected behavior. As b and c are *childrens* of a (as subitems) they inherit the visibility of a. So when you say `\begin{itemize}[<+>]` b and c may only be visible if a is